# How to query a URL (DNS lookup) using Windows terminal?

Tags: windows, terminal, ip, spam-prevention, httpbl

I am trying to use Windows' command line in order to query http:BL using their API ([link](http://www.projecthoneypot.org/httpbl_configure.php)) but can't seem to fine a command to do what I want.

I thought I should use something like:

```
ping secretkey.7.1.1.127.dnsbl.httpbl.org
```

But I'm only getting:

```
 [1] ""                                                                                  
 [2] "Pinging secretkey.7.1.1.127.dnsbl.httpbl.org [127.1.1.7] with 32 bytes of data:"
 [3] "Reply from 127.1.1.7: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128"                                   
 [4] "Reply from 127.1.1.7: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128"                                   
 [5] "Reply from 127.1.1.7: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128"                                   
 [6] "Reply from 127.1.1.7: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128"                                   
 [7] ""                                                                                  
 [8] "Ping statistics for 127.1.1.7:"                                                    
 [9] "    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),"                          
[10] "Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:"                                    
[11] "    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms"
```

Or

```
ping -a secretkey.7.1.1.127.dnsbl.httpbl.org
```

But neither seem to give me the desired output.

Any suggestion on which command to use?

UPDATE.

Using:

```
nslookup -debug secretkey.7.1.1.127.dnsbl.httpbl.org
```

I got:

```
Non-authoritative answer:
 ------------ Got answer:     HEADER: 
opcode = QUERY, id = 1, rcode = NXDOMAIN 
header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail. 
questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 1,  additional = 0      QUESTIONS: 
1.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa, type = PTR, class = IN     AUTHORITY RECORDS:     ->  168.192.in-addr.arpa 
ttl = 86399 (23 hours 59 mins 59 secs) 
primary name server = dns.netvision.net.il 
responsible mail addr = hostmaster.netvision.net.il 
serial  = 2011010100 
refresh = 1800 (30 mins) 
retry   = 900 (15 mins) 
expire  = 604800 (7 days) 
default TTL = 604800 (7 days)  ------------ Server:  UnKnown Address:  192.168.1.1  ------------ Got answer:     HEADER: 
opcode = QUERY, id = 2, rcode = NOERROR 
header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail. 
questions = 1,  answers = 1,  authority records = 3,  additional = 3      QUESTIONS: 
secretkey.7.1.1.127.dnsbl.httpbl.org, type = A, class = IN     ANSWERS:     ->  secretkey.7.1.1.127.dnsbl.httpbl.org 
internet address = 127.1.1.7 
ttl = 300 (5 mins)     AUTHORITY RECORDS:     ->  dnsbl.httpbl.org 
nameserver = ns2.httpbl.org 
ttl = 300 (5 mins)     ->  dnsbl.httpbl.org 
nameserver = ns3.httpbl.org 
ttl = 300 (5 mins)     ->  dnsbl.httpbl.org 
nameserver = ns1.httpbl.org 
ttl = 300 (5 mins)     ADDITIONAL RECORDS:     ->  ns1.httpbl.org 
internet address = 209.124.55.46 
ttl = 300 (5 mins)     ->  ns2.httpbl.org 
internet address = 66.114.104.118 
ttl = 300 (5 mins)     ->  ns3.httpbl.org 
internet address = 81.17.242.92 
ttl = 300 (5 mins)  ------------ ------------ Got answer:     HEADER: 
opcode = QUERY, id = 3, rcode = NOERROR 
header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail. 
questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 1,  additional = 0      QUESTIONS: 
secretkey.7.1.1.127.dnsbl.httpbl.org, type = AAAA, class = IN     AUTHORITY RECORDS:     ->  dnsbl.httpbl.org 
ttl = 1162 (19 mins 22 secs) 
primary name server = dnsbl.httpbl.org 
responsible mail addr = dnsadmin.projecthoneypot.org 
serial  = 1397664327 
refresh = 7200 (2 hours) 
retry   = 7200 (2 hours) 
expire  = 604800 (7 days) 
default TTL = 3600 (1 hour)  ------------ Name:    secretkey.7.1.1.127.dnsbl.httpbl.org Address:  127.1.1.7 >
```

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for `nslookup`:

```
nslookup -debug secretkey.7.1.1.127.dnsbl.httpbl.org
```

Among other information, this part is what you're looking for:

```
ANSWERS:
->  secretkey.7.1.1.127.dnsbl.httpbl.org
    internet address = 127.1.1.7
    ttl = 21236
```

An answer like `127.1.1.7` in blacklists usually means it's a positive. No answer would be a negative.

Comment: Thanks silverwind - I updated the question with the output. Any suggestion on what to look there? (I could not see "ANSWERS")

Comment: Not sure why you see so much output, but `internet address = 127.1.1.7` is what you're looking for. You could try filtering the output like this: `nslookup -debug secretkey.7.1.1.127.dnsbl.httpbl.org | findstr internet`. Though't if you're serious about DNS stuff, I'd recommend `dig`, which is available for Windows too.

Comment: Or, run without `-debug`. The section with `Non-authoritative answer:
` is relevant.